# ASP.Net MVC3 - why does the default support for JSON model binding fail to decode to enum types?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having an issue with ASP.Net MVC3 (RC2). I'm finding that the new JSON model binding functionality, which is implicit in MVC3, does not want to deserialize to a property that has an enum type.

Here's a sample class and enum type:

```
public enum MyEnum { Nothing = 0, SomeValue = 5 }
public class MyClass
{
    public MyEnum Value { get; set; }
    public string OtherValue { get; set; }
}
```

Consider the following code, which successfully passes the unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var obj1 = new MyClass { Value = MyEnum.SomeValue };
    var json = jss.Serialize(obj1);
    var obj2 = jss.Deserialize<MyClass>(json);
    Assert.AreEqual(obj1.Value, obj2.Value);
}
```

If I serialize `obj1` above, but then post that data to an MVC3 controller (example below) with a single parameter of type MyClass, any other properties of the object deserialize properly, but any property that is an enum type deserializes to the default (zero) value.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestAction(MyClass data)
{
    return Content(data.Value.ToString()); // displays "Nothing"
}
```

I've downloaded the MVC source code from codeplex but I'm stumped as to where the actual code performing the deserialization occurs, which means I can't work out what the folks at Microsoft have used to perform the deserialization and thus determine if I'm doing something wrong or if there is a workaround.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I added an answer on this thread that might help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051756/model-binding-to-enums-in-asp-net-mvc-3/9070963#9070963

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found the answer. I hope this is fixed in MVC3 RTM, but essentially what happens is the object deserializes correctly internally via `JsonValueProviderFactory`, which uses `JavaScriptSerializer` to do the work. It uses `DeserializeObject()` so that it can pass the values back to the default model binder. The problem is that the default model binder won't convert/assign an int value when the property type is an enum.

There is a discussion of this at the ASP.Net forums here:
http://forums.asp.net/p/1622895/4180989.aspx

The solution discussed there is to override the default model binder like so:

```
public class EnumConverterModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder)
    {
        var propertyType = propertyDescriptor.PropertyType;
        if(propertyType.IsEnum)
        {
            var providerValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            if(null != providerValue)
            {
                var value = providerValue.RawValue;
                if(null != value)
                {
                    var valueType = value.GetType();
                    if(!valueType.IsEnum)
                    {
                        return Enum.ToObject(propertyType, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return base.GetPropertyValue(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, propertyBinder);
    }
}
```

Then in `Application_Start`, add the following line:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new EnumConverterModelBinder();
```

Comment: This issue will be fixed in the next release of ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling this action? Have you tried:

```
$.post(
    '/TestAction', 
    JSON.stringify({ OtherValue : 'foo', Value: 5 }), 
    function(result) {
        alert('ok');
    }
);
```

Comment: I'm not calling it from a web page, I'm calling it from another application via `WebClient.UploadString()`. The post process actually does work, it's just the enum properties of the class that don't deserialize. All other properties come across just fine.

Comment: I've found the problem; the DefaultModelBinder class doesn't convert ints to Enums. http://forums.asp.net/p/1622895/4180989.aspx