# Wcf DataContract class with enum causes "'Enum value '-1' is invalid for type" error

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer

I'm getting the following exception trying to pass an object through wcf:

There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:item. The InnerException message was 'Enum value '-1' is invalid for type 'Models.SubModels.DamageLocations' and cannot be serialized. Ensure that the necessary enum values are present and are marked with EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the type has DataContractAttribute attribute.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

It is defined like:

```
[DataContract]
public class Property
{
    [DataMember]
    public PropertyDamage Damage { get; set; }

    public Property()
    {
        this.Damage = new PropertyDamage();
    }
}
```

And `PropertyDamage`:

```
[DataContract]
public enum DamageLocations
{
    [EnumMember]
    Unknown=0,
    [EnumMember]
    Front,
    [EnumMember]
    Rear
}

[DataContract]
public class PropertyDamage
{
    [Display(Name="Location of Damage:")]
    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public DamageLocations DamageLocation { get; set; }
}
```

edit - this also causes the same error:

```
public enum DamageLocations
{
    Unknown=0,
    Front=1,
    Rear=2
}
```

edit 2- Adding a default value for the enum in the ctor did not change the error:

```
    public PropertyDamage()
    {
        this.DamageLocation = DamageLocations.Unknown; //0
    }
```

Trying to research the problem, I see people getting a similiar error "Enum value '0' is invalid", and the solution was to add a 0 to the enum.

I already have a 0 item though, and the error states -1 is invalid.

What is the proper way to resolve this?

edit3 - It appears the -1's are coming from the post data, this is the post data from submitting the page.

```
Damage.DamageLocation=-1
```

Comment: Is the value of your field that you are passing a valid enum? Can you try adding values to Front and Rear?

Comment: What is the value it is receiving? My guess would be someone is using -1 as a "unknown/other/all/none/something-else"

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski Yes, I have tried setting the values. See edit. Same error though.

Comment: @MarcGravell At the wcf call point the value of the enum is -1 as the error states, the property is not set in the ctor, and instead has the default value. Shouldn't that be 0, not -1?

Comment: What happens if you change the declaration of enum to `public enum DamageLocations : uint` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell Setting it to Unknown (0) in the ctor did not remove or change the error. I feel like I'm missing something important in my mental model of how this whole thing fits together.

Comment: Please show the code that throws the exception. What happens when you simply put `return new Property()` in your service method?

Comment: @CodeCaster Hey look at that. When its replaced with new Property() it works as expected. So I dug backwards, and the -1 is coming from the http post data! See edit3

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski, and CodeCaster, thank you both very much for your time this morning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds simply like your data has the value -1.

Enums are just fancy integers. You can assign any value to an enum (within the range of the underlying type); for example:

```
enum Foo { Bar = 1 }
...
Foo foo = (Foo)1035; // perfectly fine
```

This is fine in c# but not in most serialization libraries, especially those which want to encode it as names (XmlSerializer, DataContractSerializer, etc).

So: if -1 is not a **defined** value of your enums, don't use that value in your data. If -1 has a meaning, define it in the enum.

Comment: I think you are correct, the -1 is coming from a mvc http post request. So now I'm thinking I make sure the model binder is setting -1 enums to 0... does that sound right?

Comment: @asawyer whether that is "right" is up to you; if that is what you want a -1 to do, then sure

Comment: Good point! A quick edit of the custom binder found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6099687/426894 to change -1's into 0's and its working properly. Thank you for your time and assistance, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: But in my case If I adds an enum member with -1 as value, I am getting this error. `public enum DamageLocations
{
    [EnumMember] None=-1, [EnumMember] Unknown=1,
     [EnumMember] Front=2,
     [EnumMember] Rear=3
}`.  So how can I handle this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

Change `enum DamageLocations{...}` to `enum DamageLocations:int` then try.

Comment: That is the default; this should make exactly no difference

Comment: @Pramod This made no difference. Thank you though.