# ASP.Net MVC - default model binder ignores some properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model

In my ASP.Net MVC 3 application I am posting a form from a strongly-typed view to a **controller**, however I find that some properties in the model are not populated with what was sent in the form.

Upon further investigation, I found out that the `DefaultModelBinder` ignored some of the properties of the **model**.

The `GetModelProperties` method returns the complete `PropertyDescriptorCollection`, however the `BindProperty` method was not called for all of those properties. Specifically, it was not called for the `enum` properties, though I am unsure if this is just a conincidence.

How can this problem be fixed? And if you could also give an explanation as to why this is happening that would be great.

Comment: how does your model look like, and the action method

Comment: The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051756/model-binding-to-enums-in-asp-net-mvc-3) might help you.

Comment: Thank you @dakait and @AliK! Thanks to your advice and a little tinkering, the problem has been resolved.